Can we call Oracle stored procedure and pass parameters from CSV file using Liquibase
Using liquibase, I have tried loading data in a table using the following and all is working fine
<changeSet author="your.name" id="04::dataForTable" labels="data">
    <loadData file="/db/changelog/Load_User_Data.csv" tableName="USER_DETAILS"/>
</changeSet>

I am now trying to find a way where I can, using Liquibase, call a stored procedure and pass the data as parameters from a CSV file
execute INSERT_CODE_LIST('CA60','CC','Declare', 'Short Desc');

something like
<changeSet author="your.name" id="04::dataForTable" labels="data">
    <loadData file="/db/changelog/Load_User_Data.csv" ProcedureName="<procedure Name>"/>
</changeSet>

Is this possible? I have created the stored procedure and can call it from SQL Developer and all works fine.
